# How to detect which particular public iOS framework uses a particular private iOS framework?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, dyld, otool

Please correct me if my reasoning is wrong (I assume it's correct ):

As I build an iOS app, it's output is a package `MyApp.app`, and among the other things it contains a Mach-O binary MyApp: `MyApp.app/MyApp`.
We can detect which iOS public frameworks (e.g. `UIKit`, `CoreData` etc) MyApp uses by either running `otool -L MyApp.app/MyApp`, or searching for the particular symbols with some disassemlber tool e.g. Hopper.
Now, if we meet some DYLD error for a private framework during an app's launch, e.g.

```
dyld[93664]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SomeClass
  Referenced from: /Applications/XcodeRC.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircleUI.framework/FamilyCircleUI
```

this means that `FamilyCircleUI`, which is a **private** framework, is referenced by some other **public** iOS framework. And we can't detect it with `otool -L MyApp.app/MyApp`, because public framework are not built into `MyApp`, just referenced from it!

**So, the question is**: in order to detect who's referencing `FamilyCircleUI`, do I need to run `otool -L PublicIosFramework.framework/PublicIosFramework` for each of the public frameworks used in the app, or is there much shorter way?

E.g.

1. some documentation (Apple doesn't want to provide it, so maybe there're some reversed dumps I didn't found with Google)?
2. some wild combination of `otool`+`grep`+`find`+`ls` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something fairly simple - set environmental variable `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` to `1` in your target scheme.
[image]

That in Xcode console on your app startup should yield something like:

```
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKitUI.framework/EventKitUI
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iAdCore.framework/iAdCore
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TransparencyDetailsView.framework/TransparencyDetailsView
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AdAnalytics.framework/AdAnalytics
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iAdServices.framework/iAdServices
dyld: loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSuggestions.framework/CoreSuggestions
```

However if that's not enough or maybe you'd like to automate something in the long run here are actual scripts (intended to be run as Xcode script phase) to traverse the main app executable binary and its frameworks, then recursively their referenced frameworks etc.

Script looking up `ASIdentifierManager` symbol:

```
#/bin/sh
asIdentifierManagerTimesFound=0
nm ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}|grep ASIdentifierManager
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    asIdentifierManagerTimesFound=`expr "$asIdentifierManagerTimesFound" + 1`
fi
for d in ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/*/; do
    nm $d`echo $d|awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'|awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}'`|grep ASIdentifierManager
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        asIdentifierManagerTimesFound=`expr "$asIdentifierManagerTimesFound" + 1`
    fi
done
exit $asIdentifierManagerTimesFound
```

The script deliberately fails if at least one symbol occurance is found (you can change the logic by exiting with `0`).

Here's a script if you're looking for particular framework (in my example `AppTrackingTransparency` framework) using the same strategy:

```
#/bin/sh
appTrackingTransparencyTimesFound=0
otool -l ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_PATH}|grep AppTrackingTransparency
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    appTrackingTransparencyTimesFound=`expr "$appTrackingTransparencyTimesFound" + 1`
fi
for d in ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/*/; do
    otool -l $d`echo $d|awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}'|awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}'`|grep AppTrackingTransparency
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        appTrackingTransparencyTimesFound=`expr "$appTrackingTransparencyTimesFound" + 1`
    fi
done
exit $appTrackingTransparencyTimesFound
```

Both scripts are intended to be run as last Xcode build phases (so after the app has been built).

My original use case is for self inspecting for stuff rejected on Apple review.

A somewhat related operation but around verifying referenced frameworks vs actually embedded ones is covered in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69560246/5329717